# How to solve the ERROR 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED?

Tags: spring-boot, api, nginx, tomcat

I have a frontend hosted under nginx and backend hosted under tomcat.

I got the error 405 : Method not allowed when I try to login into the application.

you will find here the config file  nginx.conf :

> 

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
            client_max_body_size 300M;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        expires off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
     location /api/app/ {
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        expires off;
        proxy_method GET;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.57.129:8080/backend-1.0/api/app/;
}
}
}
```

I added also  the following lines to web.xml in order to let the server accept GET, POST, etc. request:

> 

```
        <param-name>readonly</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
```

The connection with the database works properly when I start tomcat. But the error still existing.

Comment: Does the same request succeeds directly to `http://192.168.57.129:8080` from cUrl/Postman?

Comment: Is your spring-boot controller method to login exposed as `@GetMapping`, or is it POST?
Your nginx location proxies the requests to `/api/app` using `proxy_method GET`

Comment: Curl http://192.168.57.129:8080/backend-1.0/api/app/ show me the message of backup runing , when I type curl http://192.168.57.129:80 it show me the login page of my application.

Comment: for the spring-boot controller method , it is post method

Comment: http://192.168.57.129:8080 it shows the page of tomcat

Comment: What is relevant - what request is executed from the frontend to the backend in order to perform login?

Comment: Request URL: http://192.168.57.129/login
Request Method: POST

Comment: Request URL: http://192.168.57.129/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Not Allowed
Remote Address: 192.168.57.129:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: Remove `proxy_method GET;` line from `location /api/app/ {...}`

Comment: the same problem,  status code : 405  not allowed

Comment: If you restarted the nginx and the problem still existed, please share a snippets of your frontend calls and backend endpoints code.

Comment: for the backend I have only the .war file